# 2 bars stacked and 1 unstacked in the same x axis CHARTJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to do some combined chart as the title says. I mean when i have 3Q15 in x Axis i want to get 2 bars one after the other, the first one stacked with other and second one unstacked. Here i have a picture of what i want to get with all the CHARTJS:

[image]

```
<script>
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
};
</script>

<h3 style="text-align:center;font-weight:900">ONLINE</h3>
<canvas id="myChart6" ></canvas>
<div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
<script>

var barChartData = {
        labels: ["Ene-16", "Feb-16", "Mar-16", "Abr-16", "May-16", "Jun-16", "Jul-16", "Ago-16", "Set-16", "Oct-16", "Nov-16", "Dic-16"],
        datasets: [{
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'Logística',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.6)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'Equipamiento',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.6)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'Equipamiento1',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(130,130,130,1)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'Equipamiento2',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,100,0.6)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
            fill: false
        }]

    };

window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart6").getContext("2d");

        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {

                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'label'
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {

                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        id: "y-axis-1",
                        position: "left",
                        display:true
                    },
                    {
                        stacked: true,
                        id: "y-axis-2",
                        gridLines:{
                            display: false
                        },
                        position: "right",
                        display:true
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

    };
```

And well i'm getting this, but i don't know how to make stick together just the first 2 bars and then make it got separated the 3rd bar to get my desired chart.

[image]

Any Help would be great! I'm getting a little desperate with this new Chart JS. I'm using Chart JS 2.2.2 from http://www.chartjs.org/ .

I hope someone can give me some tip. Thanks!

Comment: closest I got is https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/0oqof3Lg/ (needs some work hiding the extra scales) but the real issue it does not want to draw the bar series on the second x-axis

Comment: Try setting 'stacked: true' for x-axis also. Hope it will work.